# Extract specific chars from a string using a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to split an email address and take out the first character and the first character after the '@'

I can do this as follows:

```
'bar@foo'.split('@').map(function(a){ return a.charAt(0); }).join('')
--> bf
```

Now I was wondering if it can be done using a regex match, something like this

```
'bar@foo'.match(/^(\w).*?@(\w)/).join('')
--> bar@fbf
```

Not really what I want, but I'm sure I miss something here! Any suggestions ?

Comment: I wonder if this would be faster. Why do you want to use regex ?

Comment: @Oliboy50: [see for yourself](http://jsperf.com/rx-mp-ca). Regex is faster than the inital code posted by the OP, but it's still nowhere near as fast as my suggestion

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem My suggestion will be faster: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24404355/1249581.

Comment: @VisioN: I saw your answer, added it to the jsperf: it's faster than the regex match version, but no where near as fast as my suggestion

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yeah, simple string search with `chatAt` will be definitely the fastest (and cross browser) approach, but it is not entirely fool proof, considering the string with no `@` character.

Comment: @VisioN: well obviously that would be a problem, but then the alternatives listed here would fail silently in the sense that they'd return something else than 2 chars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use a regex for this? just use `indexOf` to get the char at any given position:

```
var addr = 'foo@bar';
console.log(addr[0], addr[addr.indexOf('@')+1])
```

To ensure your code works on all browsers, you might want to use `charAt` instead of `[]`:

```
console.log(addr.charAt(0), addr.charAt(addr.indexOf('@')+1));
```

Either way, It'll work just fine, and [This is undeniably the fastest approach](http://jsperf.com/rx-mp-ca)
If you *are* going to persist, and choose a regex, then you should realize that the `match` method returns an array containing 3 strings, in your case:

```
/^(\w).*?@(\w)/
["the whole match",//start of string + first char + .*?@ + first string after @
 "groupw 1 \w",//first char
 "group 2 \w"//first char after @
]
```

So `addr.match(/^(\w).*?@(\w)/).slice(1).join('')` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you are quite close. Just don't `join` everything returned by `match` because the first element is the entire matched string.

```
'bar@foo'.match(/^(\w).*?@(\w)/).splice(1).join('')
--> bf
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```
matched="",
'abc@xyz'.replace(/(?:^|@)(\w)/g, function($0, $1) { matched += $1; return $0; });

console.log(matched);
// ax
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex `match` function returns an array of *all* matches, where the first one is the 'full text' of the match, followed by every sub-group. In your case, it returns this:

```
bar@f
b
f
```

To get rid of the first item (the full match), use `slice`:

```
'bar@foo'.match(/^(\w).*?@(\w)/).slice(1).join('\r')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example%3a_Defining_the_regular_expression_in_replace):

```
'bar@foo'.replace(/^(\w).*@(\w).*$/, '$1$2');  // "bf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using RegEx

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-])[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sBJsW/)

Comment: This pattern doesn't come close to being useful to the OP. It's an insufficient email validation pattern, not a pattern to get specific chars out of the string

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem The pattern above does exactly that is needed. Yes, it validates an email, but it also extracts the first chars from the two parts of email address as well.

Comment: But why would the OP use this overly complex pattern? The pattern he has returns (close to) the same match. The only difference is that he needs to `s[p]lice` the result array before calling `join`

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem Well, the OP asked for a regex :) But yes, the pattern itself may be less complex.